# Let $Q$ be a point not on the line $L(P;A)={P+tA}$. Prove that $Q-X(t_0)$ is orthogonal to $A$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Let $Q$ be a point not on the line $L(P;A)={P+tA}$ in Euclidean space $V_n$.

(a) Let $f(t)=\lVert Q-X(t) \rVert^2$, where $X(t)=P+tA$. Prove that $f(t)$ is a quadratic polynomial in $t$ and that this polynomial takes on its minimum value at exactly one $t$, say at $t=t_0$.

(b) Prove that $Q-X(t_0)$ is orthogonal to $A$.

For (a), $f(t)=\lVert (Q-P)-tA \rVert^2=t^2\lVert A\rVert^2-2t<Q-P,A>+\lVert Q-P\rVert^2$, so clearly it is a quadratic polynomial that takes on a unique minimum value.

However, I don't know how to prove (b). How should I show this part? I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you factorize the polynomial, you can easily see that the polynomial attains its minimum value at $\frac{<Q-P,A>}{\lVert A\rVert^2}$, which is $t_0$. Now plug this value in $Q-X(t_0)$ and compute $<Q-X(t_0),A>$, and you'll easily get $0$.

Answer (score 0):

First find minimum of
$f (t)=t^2 \left\| A\right\| ^2-2 t<PQ,A>+ \left\| PQ\right\| ^2$.

First derivative gives
$f' (t)=2t \left\| A\right\| ^2-2<PQ,A>$

and $f' (t)=0$  iff  $t \left\| A\right\| ^2-<PQ,A>=0$

or $t=\frac{1}{\left\| A\right\| ^2}<PQ,A>$.

Now

$Q - P -\frac{1}{\left\| A\right\| ^2}<PQ,A>A=PQ -\frac{1}{\left\| A\right\| ^2}<PQ,A>A$.

Calculating the bracket with A gives

$<PQ,A> -\frac{1}{\left\| A\right\| ^2}<PQ,A><A,A>=<PQ,A>-<PQ,A>=0$

because of $<A,A>={\left\| A\right\| ^2}$, which cancels out.

I wrote PQ for Q-P.