# How do I show that a fixed point p is orthogonal to a point q on a curve using differentiation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f: \mathscr{R} \rightarrow \mathscr{R}^n$ be a differentiable mapping with $f'(t) \neq \textbf{0}$ for all $\textbf{t} \in \mathscr{R}$.  Let **p** be a fixed point not on the image curve of $f$ as in [Fig. 2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecFv.png).  If $\textbf{q} = f(t_0)$ is the point of the curve closest to **p**, that is, if $|\textbf{p} - \textbf{q}| \leqq |\textbf{p} - f(t)|$ for all $t \in \mathscr{R}$, show that the vector $\textbf{p} - \textbf{q}$ is orthogonal to the curve at **q**.
>
> *Hint:* Differentiate the function $\varphi(t) = |\textbf{p} - f(t)|^2.$
>
> *Source: [Advanced Calculus of Several Variables](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=sZIFcJ8DJAIC)*

This problem is somewhat similar perhaps to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180920/let-q-be-a-point-not-on-the-line-lpa-pta-prove-that-q-xt-0-is-ort), but different enough for me to still be confused.

In order to show that $\textbf{p} - \textbf{q}$ is orthogonal to $f'(t_0)$, I would think the easiest way to do that would be to show that their dot product is zero.  The hint suggests that we differentiate $\varphi(t) = |\textbf{p} - f(t)|^2$, which I think is $-2f'(t)|\textbf{p} - f(t)|$.  It seems like the next step would be to evaluate this expression at $t_0$ giving $-2f'(t_0)|\textbf{p} - \textbf{q}|$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Sadly, the book has no answer key.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Remember that $f'(t)$ is a vector for each $t$.  We have
$$
    \varphi'(t) = -2 f'(t)\cdot (\mathbf{p} - f(t))
$$
So $\varphi'(t_0) = -2 f'(t_0) \cdot (\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{q})$.

1. What does the fact that $\mathbf{q}$ is the point on the curve closest to $\mathbf{p}$ tell you about $\varphi'(t_0)$ on the left?
2. What vectors are being dotted on the right?